# prevent iframe to load before javascript:toggle is launched

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I made a drop-down spoiler with (iframe) embeded video from other website in it. The proble is that the iframe has pop-up ads that jumps out when page is loaded. How could I prevent iframe from loading before spoiler is opened by clicking on button?

Here is the spoiler

```
function toggle(element) {
    if (document.getElementById(element).style.display == "none") {
    document.getElementById(element).style.display = "";


    } else {
    document.getElementById(element).style.display = "none";

    }
    } 


    <a href="javascript:toggle('hidden')">Open spoiler</a>
    <div id="hidden" style="display:none;">
    <iframe    ></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `iframe` without a `src`, and assign it the `src` on command with jQuery:

`$('iframe').attr('src', ...);`

and remove the `src` on command:

`$('iframe').attr('src', '');`

Put this in `function toggle(element)` as so:

`function toggle(element) {
    if (document.getElementById(element).style.display == "none") {
        document.getElementById(element).style.display = "";
        $('iframe').attr('src', ...);
    } else {
        document.getElementById(element).style.display = "none";
        $('iframe').attr('src', '');
    }
}`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Hide the iframe and display it only after a certain point?

CSS:

```
iframe{
  display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
var yourElement = document.getElementById('elementId');
yourElement.addEventListener('load', function(){
  document.getElementById('iframeId').display = 'inline';
}, false)
```